# AzureML remote data path

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have a MLTable data asset in Azure ML studio that I am trying to access in python and I can't figure out the structure of the path.

My datastore name is fooddb and my MLTable name is food. The MLTable was created in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio.

```
training_data_input  = Input(type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path="azureml://datastores/fooddb/paths/food")

timeseries_job = automl.forecasting(
    compute="compute",
    training_data=training_data_input,
    experiment_name="salesforecast",
    target_column_name="QTY",
    primary_metric="r2_score",
    n_cross_validations=5,
    enable_model_explainability=True,
    forecasting_settings=forecast_settings
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **azure portal**

Create **Azure Machine Learning Studio resource.**

[image]

Create the Resource

[image]

Goto to **Datastores**

[image]

Click on **New Datastore**

[image]

Give complete details

[image]

The Account key will be generated in Storage account, that will be shown later.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Go to **Storage account**

Click on **upload**.

[image]
Give the required details

[image]
Dataset uploaded

[image]

The key details which we need to give in Datastore creation is from here

[image]

[image]

[image]
Click **Next**

[image]

The Data URL is the files path in datastore that can be used as the external file path.

Answer (score 0):

To use an AzureML data (Table) asset in a job, you can pass in the asset id...

```py
# get the data asset
data_asset = ml_client.data.get(name="<asset-name>", version="<version>")

training_data_input  = Input(type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path=data_asset.id)

timeseries_job = automl.forecasting(
    compute="compute",
    training_data=training_data_input,
    experiment_name="salesforecast",
    target_column_name="QTY",
    primary_metric="r2_score",
    n_cross_validations=5,
    enable_model_explainability=True,
    forecasting_settings=forecast_settings
)
```